# Extract from string separated by colon and semicolon in R

Tags: r, string, sqldf

I have a vector of strings and I want to extract information from it. The strings look like following:

```
obs, product
  1, apple:pink lady;grade 1
  2, apple--pink lady
  3, orange
```

I wanted to extract information and organised like this:

```
obs, product_1, product_2, product_3
  1, apple, pink lady, grade 1
  2, apple, pink lady, NA,
  3, orange, NA, NA
```

I am new to programming and have tried to use sub(';.*$','',datasetname), which will return a new vector, for obs 1, I can get product 1 & 2 conbined Consequently, I will need to do another round to separate the new-formed strings. However, for obs 3 (without any special characters, colon or semicolon), the function will return the whole thing. In addition, I also need to consider some cases that the separator can be different, like "--", instead of colon and semicolon.

I am wondering how can I get what I want using sqldf, or other packages in R?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
df2 <- cbind(df1[1], read.csv(text=gsub('[:;-]+', ',', df1$product),
       header = FALSE, na.strings = "", col.names = paste0("product_", 1:3)))

df2
#   obs product_1 product_2 product_3
#1   1     apple pink lady   grade 1
#2   2     apple pink lady      <NA>
#3   3    orange      <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: You can make the `col.names` argument dynamic with `col.names = paste0("product_", 1:max(sapply(strsplit(df1$product, "[:;-]+"), length)))`

Comment: Can you explain these a bit more? I am new to this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Zuo I replaced all the delimiter to `,` with `gsub` and read the `product` column with `read.csv` to create three columns and then `cbind` with the first column